# Power BI - Dax - Average

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have table like this:

Client_ID/Type_of_product/Product_ID

C1/A/P1

C1/B/P2

C2/A/P3

I would like to filter by **Type_of_product** and calculate **number of products (in total) per client**.

When I filter **A**, there is 2 clients(C1 and C2), who have 3 products in total. So answer is 1,5

When I filter **B**, there is 1 client (C1) which has 2 products in total. So answer is 2.

Please could anyone advise me?
Many thanks :)
roman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this DAX Measure: you need to manipulate filter context to achieve your result.

```
Average NOProducts Per Customer = 
DIVIDE(
    CALCULATE(COUNT(GTA[Product_ID]),ALL(GTA), VALUES(GTA[Client_ID])),
    CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(GTA[Client_ID]))
    )
```

If we test it on a table visual:

[image: FilterManip]